# Why can't I both index and include the same column in my index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

Why can't I do something like the following? I want filters on this "common" column to be both fast and to also be able to return it without requiring a table scan.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Ix_Foo
ON Foo (ForeignKeyID, ObjectID)
INCLUDE (ObjectID)
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> *Cannot use duplicate column names in index. Column name 'ObjectID' listed more than once.*

I'd like this for queries such as this where I both want to return ObjectID as well as filter by it. The subquery here is an example of what I mean:

```
SELECT something FROM Bar
WHERE Bar.FooID IN
  (SELECT ObjectID FROM Foo WHERE ForeignKeyID=13 AND ObjectID IN (12, 13, 14, 15))
```

What am I conceptually missing?

Comment: Perhaps an inner join (on ObjectID) in my subquery might be a more realistic example but I think both exercise the same need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is `ObjectId` is already included into the index as a key column and you're trying to include it as a non-key one too, which is unnecessary.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Ix_Foo
ON Foo (ForeignKeyID, ObjectID)
```

This should be enough for your purposes.

You'd normally need to include non-key columns so that (quoting [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)):

- They can be data types not allowed as index key columns.
- They are not considered by the Database Engine when calculating the number of index key columns or index key size.

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually the leaf level in a non-filtered, non-clustered index in SQL Server has 1 row of data per row in the underlying table. The columns in the leaf level are the distinct columns from the following:

- Columns that make up the index key. (So we can navigate the index)
- A conceptual pointer to the corresponding row in the base table. (So we can get back to the corresponding row in the base table)

  - For a heap, the pointer is the RID, or row identifier
  - For a Clustered Index, the pointer is the key columns that make up the clustered index
- Any included Columns  (Extra columns stuck in for good measure)

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (id int not null, first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20))
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_t1 on t1 (id)
CREATE INDEX IX_t1_a on t1 (first_name)
CREATE INDEX IX_t1_b on t1 (first_name) INCLUDE (id)
CREATE INDEX IX_t1_c on t1 (first_name) INCLUDE (id, last_name)
CREATE INDEX IX_t1_d on t1 (first_name, last_name)
CREATE INDEX IX_t1_e on t1 (first_name, id)
```

The leaf level of IX_t1_a consists of (first_name, id)

The leaf level of IX_t1_b consists of (first_name, id)

The leaf level of IX_t1_c consists of (first_name, id, last_name)

The leaf level of IX_t1_d consists of (first_name, id, last_name)

The leaf level of IX_t1_e consists of (first_name, id)

Columns are never included twice.  In the example above, indexes a,b,c are duplicates of each other.  Likewise, indexes c and d are duplicates as well.  (There are subtle differences in the non-leaf levels depending on the uniqueness of clustered and non-clustered indexes, but for which queries the index can be used for, they are identical.)

Comment: My understanding is that there was some sort of hashing going on with the data to "reduce" it (to make it easier to find) and that this hashing would be performed on the columns in the "ON" part but the columns in the "INCLUDE" part would essentially be sorta like "denormalized" data for quick access without hitting the table while the hashed data has effectively been destroyed necessitating hitting the table. After your explanation here, I feel I misunderstand something...

Comment: Index are stored as as b-trees in sql server.  So, yes, they are organized so the data is easier to find, but not with hashing or any other kind of trickery. Kimberly Tripp does an excellent job of explaining in this [MCM Readiness Video](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/gg508878.aspx).  The video is 30 minutes long, but well worth it.